# IN clause on collection with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I have two entities: `Acknowledgement` and `Industry`. The former has a ManyToMany association with the latter, and the other way around, too.

```
@Entity
public class Acknowledgement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "acknowledgement_industry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "acknowledgement_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "industry_id"))
    private Set<Industry> industries = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Industry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "industries")
    private Set<Acknowledgement> acknowledgements = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I am trying to create a JPQL/HQL query that finds acknowledgements based on a set of IDs that are furthermore associated with a set of industry IDs - and uses the aggregate function `count`. So I want to know how many acknowledgements that satisfy these criteria. Here is some of what I tried:

```
long result = (long) this.getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(jpql)
            .setParameter("acknowledgements", new HashSet<>(acknowledgementIds))
            .setParameter("industries", new HashSet<>(industryIds))
            .getSingleResult();
```

The parameters are sets of integers. I tried with entity objects as well. For the `jpql` string, I tried the below queries (and a few variations).

**Query #1**

```
select count(a) from Acknowledgement a where a.id in :acknowledgements and a.industries in :industries
```

**Result**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 2.
```

**Query #2**

```
select count(a) from Acknowledgement a where a.id in :acknowledgements and a.industries.id in :industries
```

**Result**

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [acknowledg0_.id.industries] with element property reference [id]
```

This approach works for some other association types, but apparently not for collections.

The problem is the `IN` clause for the `industries` association. I could write a native query, but I want to avoid that. How can I find entities of type `A` that have objects of type `B` associated whose IDs are in a given set?

I hope I made myself clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT a) FROM Acknowledgement a INNER JOIN a.industries AS ind where a.id in :acknowledgements and ind.id IN :industries
```

Alternatively you could use `MEMBER OF` instead of the `IN` expression: `WHERE :industry1 MEMBER OF a.industries OR :industry2 MEMBER OF a.industries OR ...`.

Comment: Do you know of a more dynamic way of doing this so that I would not have to manipulate my query depending on how many industries I have in my set? I will look into `MEMBER OF` - thanks.

Comment: I did not hear about a more dynamic way. The problem with the dynamic way would be that it would not be clear whether `OR` or `AND` operators should be used, i.e 1. `WHERE :industry1 MEMBER OF a.industries OR :industry2 MEMBER OF a.industries` vs 2. `WHERE :industry1 MEMBER OF a.industries AND :industry2 MEMBER OF a.industries`

Comment: I changed a few things in your query, and I appear to have found a working solution. Please see my answer. I am accepting this answer because you pointed me in the right direction. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Andrei's answer, I came up with the following query that appears to work. I had tried that before, but what I was missing was the `DISTINCT` keyword within the `COUNT` function. Compared to the accepted answer, I also changed the join to be an `INNER JOIN` and used the `IN` clause on `i.id` rather than just the alias `i`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM Acknowledgement a INNER JOIN a.industries i WHERE a.id IN :acknowledgements AND i.id IN :industries
```

Comment: Related to the problem, that one should use the path with the id property instead of the path to the entity: it really depends on what your parameters are. As of my experience: if you have a list of `Long`s as parameters, then you must use the path to the id, otherwise you could use both.